# SQLAlchemy & Sqlite3. sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError)

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3, sqlalchemy

Есть таблица Products в sqlite. Файл с данными дополняется новыми и изменяется в существующих строках. В файле примерно 28 000 строк.
При этом, если я сокращаю количество строк до 500, то все работает нормально.

Помогите разобраться, почему при работе с полным файлом выдает ошибку:

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO "Products" ("KSSS_prod", "Product_Name", "Pack", "Pack_group", "Brand", "Production", "Segment", "LoB", "BO_type", "Pack_group2", "Analog_LLK", "ED_type", is_deleted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (('1000127', 'nan', 'non-ED', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 0), ('10004', 'Налив', 'non-ED', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 0))]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Это модель таблицы:

```
class Products(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Products'

    KSSS_prod = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, )
    Product_Name = Column(String)
    Pack = Column(String)
    Pack_group = Column(String)
    Brand = Column(String)
    Production = Column(String, nullable=True)
    Segment = Column(String, nullable=True)
    LoB = Column(String, nullable=True)
    BO_type = Column(String, nullable=True)
    Pack_group2 = Column(String, nullable=True)
    Analog_LLK = Column(String, nullable=True)
    ED_type = Column(String, nullable=True)
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'KSSS prod: {self.KSSS_prod}, Product Name: {self.Product_Name}'
```

Это функция добавления новых записей:

```
def create_Products(data):
    prod_for_create = []
    for row in data:
        material_exists = db.query(Products).filter(Products.KSSS_prod == row['KSSS_prod']).count()
        if material_exists == 0:
            material_list = {'KSSS_prod' : row['KSSS_prod'],
                                        'Product_Name' : row['Product_Name'],
                                        'Pack' : row['Pack'],
                                        'Pack_group' : row['Pack_group'],
                                        'Brand' : row['Brand'],
                                        'Production' : row['Production'],
                                        'Segment' : row['Segment'],
                                        'LoB' : row['LoB'],
                                        'BO_type' : row['BO_type'],
                                        'Pack_group2' : row['Pack_group2'],
                                        'ED_type' : row['ED_type'],
                                        'Analog_LLK' : row['Analog_LLK']}
            prod_for_create.append(material_list)

    db.bulk_insert_mappings(Products, prod_for_create)
    try:
        db.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print_error(row, "Ошибка целостности данных: {}", e)
        db.rollback()
        raise
    except ValueError as e:
        print_error(row, "Неправильный формат данных: {}", e)
        db.rollback()
        raise
    return prod_for_create
```

Comment: Скорее всего, это произошло из-за того, что одно или несколько значений вставляемых строк превышают максимальную длину для соответствующих столбцов в таблице.

Comment: @MaxWatson Единственные 2 поля, которые могут быть длинными (относительно, сейчас максимально 40 символов), я прописала сейчас так и все равно не помогает
`
 Product_Name = Column(String(1000))
Analog_LLK = Column(String(1000), nullable=True)
`